# What causes different capitalisation and additions like .local in advertised host names?

Tags: linux, networking, dns, dhcp, hostname

I have two Raspberry Pi boards running Linux (Raspbian). Their being totally identical gets me confused when I see their advertised host names:

The first is `kitchen.local`;
the second `BATHROOM`.

The file /etc/hostname is `kitchen` and `bathroom` respectively for both devices.

So my question is, which thing adds the `.local` or causes the second device to have all capitals in the host name?

I'm not sure how this all works and if the following matters: I'm querying the host names with Angry IP Scanner. My DHCP server is a router with OpenWRT on it. The DNS server is my modem which I believe acts as a sort of cache.

Answer (score 1):

There may be several different discovery / browsing protocols that your scanning tool is using to try to find the names of discovered devices, and there are different conventions for different protocols.

NetBIOS Name Service is very old, and traditionally uses ALL CAPS hostnames.

IETF ZeroConf supports mixed case, and uses the .local naming. 
(A note on naming: ZeroConf started life as Apple Rendezvous/Bonjour and has since been standardized by the IETF. The underlying protocols it uses are called mDNS (multicast DNS) and DNS-SD (DNS Service Discovery), so some people refer it it by those names. The most common Linux implementation is probably still Avahi, although Apple's open source mDNSResponder is used in some distros, and OpenWrt created their own mDNS daemon)

Microsoft proprietary LLMNR (link-local multicast name resolution) is like a nonstandard semi-clone of ZeroConf and also uses the .local naming, just to confuse things.

Maybe your scanner is just sticking with whatever name it discovers first via whichever protocol happens to respond first.

Comment: Thanks, this might be the most succinct and at the same time complete summary of the different mechanisms behind this seemingly simple matter. One question though: so are these host names always returned via a sort of reverse DNS query? So we do not ask the device itself for its host name but instead query some DNS server where the host has identified itself with? Why so complicated?

BTW, not sure what kind of protocols Angry IP Scanner uses. It just says "DNS": http://angryip.org/faq/hostnames.html.

Comment: @Nick mDNS works by multicasting a DNS-like query on the LAN, basically asking things like, “What is the hostname for IP address 192.168.1.3?” and the unit that has that address responds by multicasting a DNS-like answer saying “192.168.1.3 is kitchen.local”. This is a gross oversimplification of how it works, but the point is that it is all done with local multicasts of DNS-like query and answer packets, without requiring a unicast DNS server.

Comment: I see, so the unit that answers could also be the device that the hostname is aksked for itself? I wonder which devices it could be otherwise? The DHCP server?

In any case, the host name being queried using different protocols is probably the cause. So the explanations for the behaviour are probably that for either device some unit answers to one of the queries with a different protocol each, possibly due to timing, or there are just multiple devices which only reply to specific protocols.